# Radio Buttons are hidden and won't show

Tags: html, css, radio-button

ALREADY followed the suggested solutions from [Radio button is not showing in safari and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618144/radio-button-is-not-showing-in-safari-and-chrome) and did not solve the problem

**This problem is not covered in that question**

---

I am using WordPress and the theme is having an issue where radio buttons to not show up
See this sample page: http://weedsdeliver.com/test.html

Already tried

- `-webkit-appearance: radio;`
- `display: inline;`
- Even tried changing the background color with `background-color: #xxxxxx;`

This problem is persistent in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should learn how to inspect the html of your webpage in the chrome browser.  If you did you will see the following:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
height: 19px;
opacity: 0;
width: 20px;
}
```

if you change the opacity to 1 the radio buttons will appear.

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
opacity: 1;
}
```

There are some plugins for wordpress that will let you easily modify the css.  If you need more help, comment back to  me.

Comment: I agree with you. I need to learn how to read the information provided in the inspect tool. I am interested to know of this plugin you mentioned.

Comment: check out css plugins for wordpress.  kindly accept answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a style property [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) on all input radio elements in this [file](https://www.weedsdeliver.com/wp-content/themes/go/dist/css/style-shared.min.css?ver=1.4.0). Remove it or change the value to 1.

[image]